# My Minecraft servers all read no connection

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

All of my servers say that there is no connection, I don't know how to fix it so I can play on different servers, how do i fix it? I have tried doing the firewall thing, but maybe i did it wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You could have an issue with version numbers. If your local version does not match the server, you will not be able to log on. A quick scan of the minecraft forums also indicates that within the last few weeks at least there seem to have been intermittent issues with logging in on version 1.6.4. I would try waiting a bit and giving it another shot.

http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/2140951-failed-to-login-bad-login/

Comment: I had to switch down to 1.6.4 but now when i try and get into a server it says bad login, or invalid username. what does that mean?

Comment: Are you using your email instead of your minecraft username?

Comment: i am using my username, not my email adress

Comment: try using your email address